# How to set chrome driver path for centos

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am triying to run my testcase on centos but unable to set the path for driver can anyone help me to come out from this situation

I have one jar file which I want to run on sentos I have installed chrome driver on sentos server but. It is not taking driver path

Comment: Do you mean by CentOS?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the Java bindings for Selenium, you will have to specify the path to the [ChromeDriver](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads) executable via the `webdriver.chrome.driver` system property. Depending on how you actually run your tests you can do this for example via the `-D` command line switch of the `java` executable:

```
java -jar mytests.jar -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=/path/to/chromedriver
```